# Android: How to make pagination with instagram API

Tags: android, pagination, instagram

I have 29 photos on my instagram account and I want to show all these photos on my app. But I know that instagram just let me retrieve 20 photos and I also know that I can use pagination to get more photos. The problem is: I don't know how to paginate, do you know how to do it? do you know any tutorial?

Oh, I've read in some questions that some persons had used a counter parameter on URL like this: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?count=-1&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN  but it didn't work with me =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response object you get from the Instagram API will have a `pagination` object, this object contains a property called `next_url`. This is the URL you need to use to get the next page. Here is an example:

You request the original feed with the following URL:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=TOKEN
```

This gives a response like:

```js
{
   "pagination":{
      "next_url":"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/319505/media/recent?access_token=TOKEN&max_id=407185589491099817_319505",
      "next_max_id":"407185589491099817_319505"
   },
   "meta":{
      "code":200
   },
   "data":["omitted"]
}
```

Requesting the URL in `next_url` will return the next page, and so on for each additional page.

Comment: Hi @JohnAndrews `next_url` gives me an infinite loop as well. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to get 29 photos, you can specify a `count` of `29`, not `-1`. For retrieving more than 33 (limit set by Instagram), you can check out a [**Instafetch**](https://github.com/d4nyll/instafetch), a script I wrote.

Instafetch will get as many media items as you specify, in exchange for a higher API call count, as well as being slower.